# Updating xml elements using ant

Tags: xml, xslt, ant, ant-contrib

I have an XSL file, which acts as a configuration file for my application. In fact it is an XML file, which has the  elements wrapped around it. This file is called Config.xsl:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"           xmlns="http://www.example.org/Config">
 <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"               standalone="yes" />
 <xsl:template match="/">
 <Config>
      <Test>somevalue</Test>
      <Test1>someothervalue</Test1>
 </Config>
 </xsl:template>
```

I would like the change the value of element Test1 with a newvalue.

Below is my ant code, which I am using to update the values.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<project name="Scripts" default="test">
<taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antcontrib.properties" />
<taskdef name="xmltask" classname="com.oopsconsultancy.xmltask.ant.XmlTask"/>
<target name="test">
    <xmltask source="Config.xsl" dest="Config.xsl">
        <replace path="Config/Test1/text()" withText="newvalue" />
    </xmltask>
</target>
</project>
```

I would appreciate if anyone can let me know how to get this work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are confused with namespace. You must handle it before replacing anything. For more details how XML Task handle it goto `https://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2006/11/01/xml-manipulation-using-xmltask.html#paths-and-namespaces`. However, you may used this code to get our desired output:

input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns="http://www.example.org/Config">
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" standalone="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <Config>
      <Test>somevalue</Test>
      <Test1>someothervalue</Test1>
    </Config>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**ANT script:**

```
<project name="XML-VALIDATION" default="main" basedir=".">
  <taskdef name="xmltask" classname="com.oopsconsultancy.xmltask.ant.XmlTask"/>
  <target name="main">
    <xmltask source="config.xsl" dest="output.xml">
      <replace path="//:Config/:Test1/text()">xxxxxxx</replace>
    </xmltask>
  </target>
</project>
```

**output:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns="http://www.example.org/Config" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" method="xml" standalone="yes" version="1.0"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <Config>
      <Test>somevalue</Test>
      <Test1>xxxxxxx</Test1>
    </Config>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you Navin. That works like a charm. Also I am trying to update the same file so my source and seat are both XSL files and it does work.