# Concatenate using ANT

Tags: ant, replace, concatenation

Im new to ANT:
Im trying to debug an ANT script which is concatenating followed by editing the same file recursively. when I try to run this, 5 out of 10 builds failed with the following error
**java.io.FileNotFoundException:{PATH TO FILE}\file.xml (Access is denied)**

I tried adding delay before and after each step.still, no luck

Any help here would be appreciated.

```
<target name="concatxml">
<sleep seconds="1" /> 
<echo message="Concatenating file..." /> 
 <concat destfile="${location}/file.xml">
   <filelist dir="." files="${loc1}/file1.xml,${loc2}/file2.xml" /> 
 </concat>
 <echo message="Concatenating completed" /> 
<sleep seconds="1" /> 
 <echo message="doImportReq.xml is released for concatenating..." /> 
</target>

<target name="replacevalxml">
<sleep seconds="1" />
   <echo message="Replace initiated" /> 
    <replace file="${location}/file.xml" token="@DOMAIN@" value="${dev}" /> 
   <echo message="...replace completed /> 
<sleep seconds="1" />
</target>
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow.  You'll get better responses if you show us what you tried rather than telling us about it.  Edit your question to include your build.xml (at least the relevant portion of it)

Comment: I think first {loc2}/file2.xml..$ is missing and second one when ever you tried to concatenate first it working fine and creates new file, When it try to run second time it will fail because the owner of the new file may be different then user you runnring ant build.xml

Comment: Thanks Guru, for your analysis,The missing $ was a mistake..I didnt get the second point you highlighted.How do I check who is the owner and even if that changes how do I stop that from happening

Comment: This is an aside... You're likely going to have a bad time doing a <replace> (regex) on a xml file (non-regular).  look into the xslt task and this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19694880/updating-xml-elements-using-ant

Comment: it would be helpful to see how your calling these targets.  I'm also confused by teh for-loop tag... ant doesn't have a for loop.

Comment: Im using foreach task from ANT Contrib

Answer (score 0):

I noticed this:

```
files="${loc1}/file1.xml,{loc2}/file2.xml"
```

That should be `${loc2}` and not `{loc2}`. I don't know if that's a problem or not...